# Explain on adding a Sass file to my main Sass file

Tags: html, css, sass

I currently have a main style.sass that outputs to my main style.css file. However, in the same folder I have a _var.sass file that I want to have store all of my variables.

I have tried using the `@import var` in my style.sass but nothing seems to work. Can someone explain to me what the problem is? Do i have to output the _var.sass file to a css file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @import is a scss thing, not a sass one, create a main.scss that imports all sass file

Comment: So I would output that main scss file to the main css file and important all my sass files into that main scss file? Hope that doesn't sound confusing..

Comment: Yep, get a look at this project : https://github.com/ayrtondumas/live-sass-rendering/tree/master/app, the sass directory content the scss main and all the sass files and it is rendered as a css in the css directory, if you are using webpack or gulp, dont forget to edit your task and add the scss file in the watch :)

Comment: cool. Thanks Ayrton!

Answer (score 0):

To import *.SASS* file in another one, create a *main.SCSS* importing all sass files (more details in the question comments)